# How to assign classname to elements inside map in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add className inside map using ternary operator

```
{data.map((data) => (<div className="questionbox"><p key={data.id} className={`newquestbox ${questid === data.id && "completed"}`}> {data.id + 1}</p></div>))}
```

this is toggling of the class, but I want to assign class name if the condition is true assign the classname to complete that should not change untill I refresh the screen.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  data.map((data) => (
    <div className={data.className} key={data.id}>
       <p className={`newquestbox ${questid === data.id && 'completed'}`}> 
         {data.id + 1}
       </p>
     </div>));
}
```